# Android - Can't display image from filepath / Can't save image to device

Tags: java, android, image, uri

I'm making a simple notebook app, in which a note can have an image attached to it. I can take a photo just fine, and after the photo has been taken, it is correctly displayed in an imageview inside the note. After the note has been saved, the path to the photo is saved in a database. The path is correctly saved. Next, when the user opens the note, the path is correctly found in the database -- **however**, I am not able to load it into the imageview. Rather, the imageview turns white. As I manually take a look into the folder where the image is supposed to be saved, I see that the image isn't being saved to the phone or SD card at all, and I have no idea how to save it. I've been looking all over the internet and StackOverflow, but haven't found a solution.

```
public void onIcTakePhotoClick(View icon) {
    File imageFile = null;
    Intent takePictureIntent;

    try {
        imageFile = ImageHelper.createImageFile(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (imageFile != null) {
        mImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        //mImagePath = ImageHelper.getImagePath(imageFile);
        takePictureIntent = ImageHelper.dispatchTakePictureIntent(this, imageFile);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ImageHelper.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    } else {
        // error message
    }
}
```

All of the above (creating a file, a path, and an intent) work well:

```
public static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    return image;
}

public static Intent dispatchTakePictureIntent(Context context, File photoFile) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                "com.bergdahl.notebook.fileprovider",
                photoFile);
        //takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        return takePictureIntent;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The filepath ends up looking like this: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myname.notebook/files/Pictures/JPEG_20160824_213643_135920553.jpg". Next I get the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ImageHelper.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                ImageHelper.handleCameraPhoto(this, imageView, mImagePath);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In which I use methods created by the Android team (https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):

```
public static void handleCameraPhoto(Activity context, ImageView imageView, String imagePath) {
    if (imagePath != null) {
        ImageHelper.setPic(imagePath, imageView);
        ImageHelper.galleryAddPic(context, imagePath);
    }
}

public static void setPic(String imagePath, ImageView imageView) {

    /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
    /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

    /* Get the size of the ImageView */
    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

    /* Get the size of the image */
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
    }

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);

    /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public static void galleryAddPic(Activity context, String imagePath) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    File f = new File(imagePath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

And finally, the code for opening up the note later:

```
if (mNote.getFilePath() != null) {
        mImagePath = mNote.getFilePath();
        //ImageHelper.handleCameraPhoto(this, imageView, mNote.getFilePath());

        //File file = new File(mImagePath);
        //imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(mImagePath));

        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:" + mNote.getFilePath());
        //imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
```

In the manifest, I've specified the permission for writing to external storage. So, to reiterate, I need help figuring out how to save the image that I've taken onto the device, so that I can later load it into an imageview next time the user opens the note. Thank you in advance for the help!

EDIT: I tried the image.createNewFile()-method, but the outcome is sadly the same. The boolean test is true.

```
public static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    /*
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );
    */

    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg");

    if (!image.exists()) {
        try {
            boolean test = image.createNewFile();
            Log.d("createImageFile", test + "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

EDIT again: The image now correctly shows up on an emulator, but it doesn't work on my actual device. The emulator runs 6.0, my device 6.0.1. My device has granted permissions and has external storage. I've been trying to change the directory, but to no success.

Comment: Android device version used?

Comment: Create a regular file instead of a temp file.

Comment: I'm testing on a device running Android 6.0.1. I'm very new to file-creating, so I'm not sure how to make a regular file. Could you provide me with an example on how I'd create one?

Comment: Just replace `File.createTempFile` with `File.createNewFile`.

Comment: I've tried, but createNewFile works differently, in that it can only be called on an already created instance of a File object (i.e. File file = new File(params), file.createNewFile()), and I'm not sure how I'd go about using it in my example. Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: you need to run time permission.. First?

Comment: @PrerakSola, I tried using createNewFile; I updated the bottom of my original question with the code I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
mImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

with

```
mImagePath = "file:" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I've already tried this, and it make no difference.

Comment: No prob :) Have you tried passing  mImagePath instead of imageFile to ImageHelper.dispatchTakePictureIntent. Pass the file path that you got instead of the File itself.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 6 you won't have the read/write permission after installing even if you have declared it in your manifest. You have to ask for it first at runtime:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

For testing purposes you can give your app the permissions in the app settings menu without implementing the query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is very useful for later, but I've already given my device the appropriate permissions manually, so sadly this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add the Permission runtime..

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    {
        if (checkPermission())
        {
            // Code for above or equal 23 API Oriented Device 
            // Create a common Method for both
   ///take camera caputure code

        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
  else
    {

       // Code for Below 23 API Oriented Device 
       // Create a common Method for both
    }
```

Now adding  **checkPermission()** and **requestPermission()**

```
 private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Your_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Your_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(Your_Activity.this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Your_Activity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
            } else {
                Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! This is very useful for later, but I've already given my device the appropriate permissions manually, so sadly this is not the issue.

Comment: Well can you provide the ImageHelper?

Comment: Ah, every single method from my ImageHelper class is in the original question :) The only thing not listed there is a basic request code (public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;), which isn't of much interest.